# C++: string operator overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, std

Can I overload existing function/operator in existing class?

I was trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string& string::operator<<(const string& str) {
  this->append(str);
}
```

But this gives me error:

```
test.cpp:5: error: too few template-parameter-lists
```

How can I do this? Or I can't?

Comment: Are you really trying to return a `string&` (as opposed to something like an `ostream&`)?  Rather than introduce syntax I think you're better off just doing what you want, i.e. if you have a `std::string` named `x` and you want to append `y`, use the existing mechanisms in `std::string` to do that (such as `x += y`) without adding a `<<` overload.  If on the other hand this is a typo and you really mean to print to a stream, please update your question.

Comment: @KevinGrant Well this is not a homework or work question. It is simply a practice of operator overloading and class.

Comment: @KevinGrant And I think these two are not contradicting? `ostream#<<` is another function other than `string#<<` right? And << has associativity of left-to-right so it won't affect cout.

Comment: Yes, `operator<<` on an `ostream&` is intended to modify a stream instead of a string; that's different than what you wrote but I thought maybe you actually meant to do this.  (It's much more typical to overload `<<` to deal with a stream.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't add member functions to a class unless you modify that class' definition.  Use a free function instead:

```
string& operator<<(string & lhs, const string & rhs) {
    return lhs += rhs;
}
```

Comment: So there is no such a thing like "re-open class"?

Comment: @texasbruce: No, there is not.  But from the user's perspective, this will have the exact same semantics as a member.

Comment: @Benjamin : how compiler resolves this type overloading? how it differentiate a member operator function and free operator function.

Comment: @Sachin: Members are declared in the class and have one less argument than their free-function counterparts, since the calling object acts as the first argument.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley But for other non-operator function, can you use the same thing? I tried to change the operator to some literals and it tells me the name is not a member function. Is there anything around to do it or simply we cannot?

Comment: @texasbruce: No, you cannot add member functions to a class. What advantage is there in doing so?  Also, ignore my previous comment about it not working properly except if it's placed in namespace std, I was thinking of something else.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I was working with Ruby all the time and I don't like some member functions provided in the standard library so I simply "re-open" the class and make my own implementation. So I assume all classes are all "sealed" in C++? If I want to overload/create new member function, I have to create a new class and inherit it?

Comment: @texasbruce: The standard library containers are not designed to be inherited from, they do not have virtual destructors.  What's so wrong with just writing free functions?  Not everything has to be a member.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I have this (mis)conception that for OO language, functions/variables/etc. should always belong to an object, and also free function can cause name conflict. Maybe I should make a namespace or a class to enclose the free functions?

Comment: @texasbruce: Yes, it is a misconception.  [Non-Member functions improve encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197).  Also, name conflicts are resolved by (in addition to namespaces) argument types.  If you have two functions with the same name which take the same argument types, then you have a conflict, otherwise, you're fine.  And if anyone can add member functions to a class at their whim, you'd have the exact same problem (with respect to name conflicts) with member functions as you have with free functions.

Answer (score 0):

I defer to Benjamin's answer for creating a stream-like interface on a `string` object. However, you could use a `stringstream` instead.

```
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream ss;
ss << anything_you_want;

std::string s = ss.str(); // get the resulting string
ss.str(std::string());    // clear the string buffer in the stringstream.
```

This gives you the stream-like interface you want on a `string` without needing to define a new function.

This technique can be used generally to extend the functionality of a `string`. That is, defining a wrapper class that provides the extended functionality, and the wrapper class also provides access to the underlying `string`.

Comment: Sorry maybe I should make it more clear.. My main question is how to overload a member function that already exists in an existing class, but not how to use string...

Comment: @texasbruce: In your particular example, you were wanting to add a new operator, as the `string` does not define a `<<` operator method for itself. However, I did update the answer to explain the motivation. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use

> std::ostringstream

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "Hello" << " " << "world";

    std::string s = ss.str(); 
    ss.str(std::string()); 

    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/rkanzeniI